# Jython and ImageJ : cannot find jython.jar

Tags: jython, imagej

I want to use an imageJ plugin (that I downloaded) coded in python. I put the .py file in the ImageJ plugin folder, and then I installed it using the Plugin>install on ImageJ. It now appears in the plugin list. However, when I try to use it, I get the following error:

> Jython.jar was not found in the plugins folder or is outdated.

There is a jython.jar in the jars folder of ImageJ, but I still tried to install a [newer version of jython](http://www.jython.org/downloads.html). I put the new downloaded jython.jar in the jars folder of imageJ, but it still does not work.

I am using a windows 10 computer, with  ImageJ 1.48v, and I installed both versions 2.5.4rc1 and 2.7 of jython.

Could someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Better ask this question on the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net). It is usually sufficient to just put the script file into the `./scripts` folder of your Fiji/ImageJ installation. Before posting, make sure your ImageJ is up to date.